# Android 12 DualSense/ DualShock support via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-12, gamepad-api

Android 12 added some new nice features to the controller API like rumble support. In Android 12 it's also possible to process the gyroscope and touchpad inputs from a DualSense/ DualShock controller via Bluetooth. How can an app process touchpad and gyroscope data from a DualSense/ DualShock controller? The official Remote Play app from Sony is able to do that but in my app for example the controller touchpad always acts as a mouse input (and even shows a mouse pointer inside the activity) and I don't know how to disable that. Does anyone already have experience with this or are there examples available anywhere which I didn't found?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably doable with [WebHI](https://web.dev/hid/). I am aware of a [project](https://github.com/TheBITLINK/WebHID-DS4) that provides a WebHID-based driver, so you can get access to the sensors in the controller.

Comment: My apps are native Android apps and even if I would build Web-Apps, WebHI is not supported in Android webviews. I know you can handle controller inputs natively on Android via [USB-Host mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host), I use this already for Dualshock and Dualsense gamepads but since Android 12 you can access touchpad and gyroscope natively via the official Android controller API and that's what I'm interested in.